# Looking for a package for sublime like task list in notepad++?

Tags: sublimetext3

The package should work as:

1. I specify a word
2. The package open a (dock) window, show all lines in the source file that have the word.
3. I could use the lines in dock window to jump between the source file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the task list in notepad++ is like, but it sounds like you want something to search for `TODO` entries. Take a look at https://github.com/robcowie/SublimeTODO. Though assuming your tagging is accurate, you are using ST3, and this plugin has not been ported. If that is true, you may want to check out https://github.com/dnatag/SublimeTODO, which is supposed to provide the ST3 compatibility. Note I haven't tested it, but based on some of the comments in the pull request, it seems like it might work.